# Limit Calculation - Sequences at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you help me calculate the following limit ?

$$\lim_ {n \to \infty} \frac{ 1- (1-\frac{1}{n} )^4 }{1- (1-\frac{1}{n})^3 }$$

Intuitively, I can see that the numerator decays to zero much faster than the denominator.
But how can I show it formally? (I tried to divide by $ \frac{1}{n} )^4 $ and by $\frac{1}{n})^3$ but without any success.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier if you change notation. We are looking at $\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}=\dfrac{(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3)}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint Divide the numerator and the denominator by $(1-1/n)$ to get:

$$ \frac{ 1- (1-\frac{1}{n} )^4 }{1- (1-\frac{1}{n})^3 }= \frac {1+(1-1/n)+(1-1/n)^2+(1-1/n)^3} {1+(1-1/n)+(1-1/n)^2} $$

Now it is easy to show that the limit is $4/3$

Comment: the power of $(1-\frac1n)$ in denominator is $3$ or $2$.

Comment: I thought it was 2. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{ 1- (1-\frac{1}{n} )^4 }{1- (1-\frac{1}{n})^3 }=\frac{(n-1)^4-n^4}{\{(n-1)^3-n^3\}n}=\frac{-4n^3+6n^2-4n+1}{-3n^3+3n^2-n}=\frac{4+\frac1n()}{3+\frac1n()}$$

So, the limit is $\frac 4 3$

Comment: If you multiplied the numerator by $n^4$ the numerator should be $n^4-(n-1)^4$

Comment: @Amr, thanks for your observation. Could you please verify?

Comment: I didnt understand. emm verify what

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Apply L'Hôpital's rule, since you have the form $\frac{0}{0}$.